# navigationController not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIView with a UITableView inside it , i am trying to push a view using :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
QSTNewsDetailViewController *news = [[QSTNewsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newsDetailView" bundle:nil];
row = [data objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSString *titulo = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *contenido = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *imagen = [[NSString alloc] init];

if (!([row objectForKey:@"titulo"] == [NSNull null])) {
    titulo = [row objectForKey:@"titulo"];
} else {
    titulo = @"";
}
if (!([row objectForKey:@"contenido"] == [NSNull null])) {
    contenido = [row objectForKey:@"contenido"];
    contenido = [contenido stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} else {
    contenido = @"";
}
if (!([row objectForKey:@"imagen"] == [NSNull null])) {
    imagen = [row objectForKey:@"imagen"];
} else {
    imagen = @"";
}
[news setTitulo:titulo];
[news setNoticiaContenido:contenido];
[news setUrlImagen:imagen];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:news animated:YES];
}
```

but the app does nothing, i have the same exact instruction in another view and it works perfectly.

When i debug the app i am sure that the view i am trying to push exists. Any ideas ? this is driving me crazy !!!

Comment: Basic question, but are you sure that the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is triggered when you tap on a row?

Comment: @workingDev Sure as dead LOL i have a breakpoint right in the presentViewController line.

Comment: Is the table view controller inside of a navigation controller? If not, then `[self navigationController]` will return `nil` and nothing will happen.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to say to check if `[self navigationController]` is nil or not...

Comment: @rmaddy this table is inside a UINavigationController but it returns nil when i try to make a NSLog in fact i can go back to another view pushing the back button

Comment: The 1st line of your question states that you have a `UIView` with a `UITableView` inside it. In the code you posted, what exactly is `self`? Is it a `UITableViewController` or something else?

Comment: @rmaddy it is a UIViewController subclass, the tableView is an outlet